# zip не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python, zip

Не получается решить проблему с кодом из задачи в книге  a byte of python.
Я понимаю что этот вопрос уже задавали много раз, но я так и не понял как решить эту проблему.

1. вот код

   ```
    import os
    import time

    # 1. Файлы и каталоги, котрые необходимо скоприрвать, собираются в список.
    source = ['D:\\Python']
    # для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать двойные кавычки внутри строки. 

    # резервные копии должны храниться в основном катологе резерва.
    target_dir = 'D:\\backup' # сам путь

    # 3. файли перемещаются в zip-архив.
    # 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
    target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

    # 5. Используем команду "zip" для перемещения файлов в zip-архив.
    zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

    # Запускаем создание резервной копии
    print(zip_command)
    if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
        print("Резервная копия успешно создана в", target)
    else:
        print("Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ")
   ```
2. Выдаёт вот такую ошибку.

   ```
    zip -qr D:\backup\20201219145116.zip D:\Python
    "zip" не является внутренней или внешней
    командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
    Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ
   ```
3. Саму программу zip я установил. И путь до папки тоже указал верно, но всё равно ничего  не работает.

[image: Саму программу zip я установил.]

[image: Путь до папки тоже вроде бы верно указал]

Можете пожалуйста сказать что я делаю не так. Ведь все способы на этом сайте я уже перепробовал и ничего не выходит. Буду очень благодарен если кто то поможет.

Comment: а вы попробуйте для начала `zip -qr D:\backup\20201219145116.zip D:\Python` выполнить в консоли - так будет понятно, питон виноват или нет, может просто zip не прописал в переменных окружении и его соответственно система не видит, так что или прописать местонахождения zip в переменные окружения или указывать полный путь до zip

Comment: @Zhihar когда вставляю : zip -qr D:\backup\20201219145116.zip D:\Python в консоль, то пишет что  "zip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Я просто и программу установил и путь указал тот. Но так ничего и не работает.

Comment: значит у вас именно не прописан путь в переменных окружения - поищите в сети как это делается или укажите к zip.exe прямой путь

Comment: Терминал перезапускали после обновления переменных окружения?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов да

Comment: В следующий раз, пожалуйста, обрезай скриншоты, чтобы в них на было огромного пустого белого ненужного пространства.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов терминал перезапускал, но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: @Эникейщик,  когда меняю на ...bin\bin ошибка остаётся такая же

Answer (score 2):

Программа лежит в папке `.../bin/bin`, а в `PATH` только один `bin`.